# Getting the channels that are in some way using a given queue in RabbitMQ

Tags: java, rabbitmq

I'm looking to replicate something I can see in RabbitMQ Web UI -- it will tell me what are the consumers (in the form of their channels) are currently connected to a given queue.

How can I know that information from the RabbitMQ Java API? Is it possible? The best I could find was how to know how many consumers a given queue has, but nothing better than that.

If the Java API can't provide that, is there some straight-forward and not very cpu intensive way of getting that info with RabbitMQ CLI (rabbitmqadmin)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `API`:
`http://rabbitmqhost:15672/api/queues/{vhost}/{queue_name}`

es:

`http://localhost:15672/api/queues/%2F/test_3`

the json you will get is:

```
{

    "name": "test_3",
    "vhost": "/",
    "durable": true,
    "auto_delete": false,
    "exclusive": false,
    "arguments": { },
    "node": "rabbit@t-srv-rabbit-cos02",
    "consumer_details": [
        {
            "arguments": { },
            "prefetch_count": 0,
            "ack_required": false,
            "exclusive": false,
            "consumer_tag": "amq.ctag-L417KXSKpmghjHXmRpcHkw",
            "queue": {
                "name": "test_3",
                "vhost": "/"
            },
            "channel_details": {
                "name": "127.0.0.1:50427 -> 127.0.0.1:5672 (5)",
                "number": 5,
                "user": "test",
                "connection_name": "127.0.0.1:50427 -> 127.0.0.1:5672",
                "peer_port": 50427,
                "peer_host": "127.0.0.1"
            }
        }
    ],
```

About Java you can use [HOP (RabbitMQ HTTP API client for Java, Groovy, and other JVM languages)](https://github.com/rabbitmq/hop)

Answer (score 0):

You could try with [rabbitmq rest api](http://hg.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-management/raw-file/3646dee55e02/priv/www-api/help.html), and as you have mentioned `rabbitmqadmin`, amybe some info from `rabbitmqctl` as well.